# How do I make a upload form that will upload the file in php, and show result in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How do I make a upload form that will upload the file in php and I would like to make it jquery(with ajax) so that it returns a percentage too show the user that he is still uploading the file.
Would like to do this with no installation libraries,I.E  APC,uploadprogress

Comment: IIRC file uploading with AJAX is messy and requires a hidden iframe due to security restrictions / limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Use flash uploader like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)
This is the most simple solution as it's jQuery enabled library which utilizes a tiny transparent 1 pixel flash.

Flash can provide you with a lot of options: filter file selection by extension, multiple uploads, upload progress :).

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do it in an elegant way with PHP/Ajax/jQuery only.

Consider using java applet [JumpLoader](http://jumploader.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If old browsers are'nt a concern, you can do this with HTML5's File API.

It's all very technical, and you would have to read up on it yourself, but here's an example page that accepts images for upload with HTML5 only, no iFrames or PHP : [base64img.com](http://base64img.com)

Once the file is uploaded, the data can be sent to PHP with Ajax and stored or manipulated serverside, or you can use localstorage or if possible do what you need to do directly in javascript, depends on what exactly you intend to do with the file.

The HTML5 File API has built in solutions for progressbars and a bunch of handlers for loading, start, complete etc.

If older browsers are a concern, you could have a PHP fallback or something similar.